# Pass Reference in Class

Tags: c++, class, reference, types, linked-list

I am totally confused. In this example which is part of my class, I have:

```
public:
        typedef DoubleLinkedNode<DataType> Node;    
private:
            const DataType* fValue;
            Node* fNext;
            Node* fPrevious;
            DoubleLinkedNode(): fValue((const DataType*)0){
                fNext = (Node*)0;
                fPrevious = (Node*)0;
            }
```

Which means `fValue` is a `const DataType*` , now I want to apply/define data type like `string` or `int` to `fValue` by this part:

```
    DoubleLinkedNode( const DataType& aValue ){

        std::cout << "  --  "  << aValue << std::endl;
    }
```

I am confused , what exactly I must write there and why? How can I define `aValue` to my `fValue` ?!
(note: The `std::cout << "  --  "  << aValue << std::endl;` is just for test)

Comment: a side note - you don't need to cast `0`

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. Are you trying to print `*fValue`?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do here, but if you want to construct DoubleLinkedNode with fValue pointing to the address of aValue (which was passed to the constructor by reference) you need to define your constructor this way:

```
DoubleLinkedNode( const DataType& aValue ) : fValue(&aValue) {
        std::cout << "  --  "  << aValue << std::endl;
}
```

Note that it's not 100% safe to do this, since you can accidentally call this constructor with an *rvalue* reference (to simplify things: a reference to an object that gets destroyed right after the function call). For instance, the following code will not raise a compilation error:

```
std::string s = "Hello ";
DoubleLinkedNode<std::string> node = DoubleLinkedNode<std::string>(s + "World");
```

even though `s + "World"` is a temporary value which will be promptly destroyed after the constructor call, and now fValue will point to an invalid memory location. This is very bad, since you won't get any warning during compilation, but you will get some very hard-to-debug behavior at runtime.

Therefore, it might be better to make a constructor that expects pointers instead of references:

```
DoubleLinkedNode( const DataType* aValue ) : fValue(aValue) {
        std::cout << "  --  "  << aValue << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `fValue` is a pointer, and DoubleLinkedNode() takes an object by reference, you need to dereference the pointer, like this:

```
DoubleLinkedNode(*fValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

If `fValue` is a pointer, it needs to point at some variable created elsewhere.  So what code is responsible for the lifetime of the pointed-at value `*fValue`?

If the class needs to create the value itself and `fValue` really needs to be a pointer, it can use `new` and `delete`:

```
template <typename DataType>
DoubleLinkedNode<DataType>::DoubleLinkedNode( const DataType& aValue )
  : fValue( new DataType(aValue) ), fNext(0), fPrevious(0)
{}
template <typename DataType>
DoubleLinkedNode<DataType>::~DoubleLinkedNode() {
    delete fValue;
}
```

But I suspect the design might work out better if `fValue` were not a pointer in the first place:

```
private:
    const DataType fValue;

// Requires a default constructor for DataType.
template <typename DataType>
DoubleLinkedNode<DataType>::DoubleLinkedNode()
  : fValue(), fNext(0), fPrevious(0)
{}
template <typename DataType>
DoubleLinkedNode<DataType>::DoubleLinkedNode( const DataType& aValue )
  : fValue(aValue), fNext(0), fPrevious(0)
{}
```